# laravel one to one retrieve many results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have business and location table and they have one to one relationship. Everything works fine so far but they problem is I only find 1 result.

However business_id which is a foreign key in location table has loads of results.

My business table has id from 5-95 and these are the records I want to return

so in my location table I also have business_id which is from 5-95.

How do I tell eloquent to retrieve these specific records?

At this moment I have:

```
function transportProfile() {
    $type = 2;
    $business = Business::where('type', $type)->get();
    $location = Business::find(3)->locations;
    echo $location;
    return view('userProfile', compact('business', 'location'));
}
```

So to clarify business table has id from 5-95 and location table has business_id from 5-95 I want to return results from those 2 tables so I can use it in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$businesses = Business::where('type', $type)->with('location')->get();
```

To display the data:

```
@foreach ($businesses as $business)
    {{ $business->location->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi! You are a *, I was looking for something like this and I never found anything so in location table I want to output slug and business name can you do that?

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas you can do `{{ $business->location->slug }}`. Also, try to do `{{ dd($businesses) }}` which will show you all the data with its structure, so you get the idea how to work with it.

Comment: @foreach($business as $business_name)
                <option value="{{$business_name->location->slug}}">{{$business_name->name}}</option>
            @endforeach

Comment: and this gives me back trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas looks like one of the businesses doesn't have a location. If this is the case, just check if it's empty `{{ empty($business_name->location) ? 'no-slug' : $business_name->location->slug }}`